# remove header from panda series

Tags: python, pandas

I got series as below

```
p = pd.Series(y['saving'].values, index=y['date'])
print(p)

date
2019-01-01     29157
2019-02-01     27414
2019-03-01     32655
2019-04-01     55164
2019-05-01     98440
2019-06-01    109610
```

but i would like to convert it into (without date column header) but to keep original format (pandas.core.series.Series)

```
2019-01-01     29157
2019-02-01     27414
2019-03-01     32655
2019-04-01     55164
2019-05-01     98440
2019-06-01    109610
```

how i can remove header then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = pd.Series(y['saving'].values, index=y['date'].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` property of the index does it:

```
p.index.name = ''
```